# execute a command

Tags: linux, shell

I have script file where a command is stored in a variable

First i got the command (assume "ls -l " command)

```
cmd=`cat /proc/2345/cmdline`
```

now doing

```
echo $cmd
```

outputs

```
ls -l
```

Now how to use $cmd to actually execute that command. which is ls -l

Comment: Please use quotes ("") with variables, cmd="cat /proc/2345/cmdline" , will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks i will check that too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is:

```
$cmd
```

Answer (score 6):

BASH FAQ [entry #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: +1, its really nice to see an updated BASH guide available. Others were starting to stagnate.

Answer (score 3):

```
eval $cmd
```

Just `$cmd` will work in many cases, but not always. See the article "[Bash: Why use eval with variable expansion?](http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Why_use_eval_with_variable_expansion%3F)" for further details.

Comment: Your reference makes no mention of the [evils of eval](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Comment: @Dennis: Thanks, good link. The question is: Does it apply to this case?

Comment: Yes, because the file `/proc/2345/cmdline` could contain something scary like `rm -rf /` (but in this case, that danger also applies to just executing `$cmd` directly).

Comment: @Dennis: Exactly: That's not a problem of `eval` but rather a problem of the requirement, which is to blindly execute another process' command line. The question is rather: Could someone start a "harmless" process that turns into an "evil" process after "eval $cmd"-ing?

Answer (score 2):

if you have no business to store it in a variable, then don't. Just run it as usual.

```
cat /proc/2345/cmdline
```